# How to delete a single data value from a Table

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two columns in my table and i need a single data value from one column gone since it’s too high of a number.

I only know how to delete entire rows or columns but I don't know how to tackle this

Comment: `iris[,1][iris[,1] >= 5] <- NA` will turn to `NA` any value in the first variable of the `iris` dataset that is 5 or greater.

Comment: I’m planning on doing a two sample t-test and i will be performing histograms,boxlplot, and med,median mode will it affect it? is there any way to delete just a single value from one column or is the only way N/A : btw my value i want to get rid of is above 100 compared to the rest that is  below 60

Comment: `NA` is the only way. Just add `na.rm = TRUE` in your functions to ignore the NA.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the column with `if_else()` and a condition that is only satisfied by the element you would like to change (which could be the row number).